# Mouse Flickering/Disappearing

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, cursor, macbook-pro, flicker

When I move my mouse around in Ubuntu 12.10 it flickers. When it's not moving it disappears.

Any ideas?

### Info

- Macbook Pro 7.1
- Nvidia 320m
- Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Same here - it flickers (discrete pixels randomly changing color) only in the upper part of the screen. It is related to mouse move only, and if I do revert to original theme it somehow disappear. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

**software sources -> Additional Drivers**

and see what driver your nvidia card is using.
I have the same setup and found that using the *nvidia-experimental-304* driver worked best for me.
[image: Example]

Scroll all the way to the right to see the names of the drivers, and see [this post for more information on which drivers allow you to shutdown properly.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2127691&p=12566794#post12566794)

Refer to [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Quantal#Video.2BAC8-Graphic_Card) for more information on fully utilizing your macbook pro 7,1 with ubuntu 12.10.