# How can I list connected monitor(s) with xrandr?

Tags: command-line, python, display, resolution, xrandr

I'm working on developing a python application for Ubuntu that enables a user to have their desired resolution without requiring graphics drivers.

 In order to do this I've been using `xrandr`, which so far, has been pretty useful

However, I now have a problem; how can I detect the monitor name? I was intending to use a terminal command through `os.system`, modifying the terminal output to get the required monitor output, and then storing it within the program. Unfortunately, despite much searching, I have been unable to find out how I can do this.

Is there any way in which I can do this?

To sum it up: *I'm looking for a terminal command that gives me the monitor name, such `VGA1` or `DVI-0`*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure how you are going to apply it in your application (*"enable a user to have their desired resolution without requiring graphics drivers"* ?), but:

#### A terminal command to list connected screens

```bsh
xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
```

This wil give you the connected screens for further processing, like:

```
VGA-0
DVI-I-1
```

#### Since you mention python, the snippet below will also list connected screens:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

def screens():
    output = [l for l in subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()]
    return [l.split()[0] for l in output if " connected " in l]

print(screens())
```

This wil also give you the connected screens, like:

```
['VGA-0', 'DVI-I-1']
```

#### Note

Note the spaces around `" connected "` in the searched string. They are needed to prevent mismatches with `disconnected`.

## EDIT 2019

Using python, not necessary to use `xrandr` or any other system call at all. Better use Gdk:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gdk

allmonitors = []

gdkdsp = Gdk.Display.get_default()
for i in range(gdkdsp.get_n_monitors()):
    monitor = gdkdsp.get_monitor(i)
    scale = monitor.get_scale_factor()
    geo = monitor.get_geometry()
    allmonitors.append([
        monitor.get_model()] + [n * scale for n in [
            geo.x, geo.y, geo.width, geo.height
        ]
    ])

print(allmonitors)
```

Example output:

```
[['eDP-1', 0, 0, 3840, 2160], ['DP-2', 3840, 562, 1680, 1050]]
```

Depending on the desired info, you can make your choice from https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gdk-3.0/classes/Monitor.html

Comment: Note that the Python solution only lists displays that have not been disabled via `xrandr`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the bash command with popen:

```py
import os
list_display = os.popen("xrandr --listmonitors | grep '*' | awk {'print $4'}").read().splitlines()
# or based on the comment of this answer 
list_display = os.popen("xrandr --listmonitors | grep '+' | awk {'print $4'}").read().splitlines()
```

```bash
xrandr --listmonitors | grep '*' | awk {'print $4'}
xrandr --listmonitors | grep '+' | awk {'print $4'}
```

or I wrote a old gist on the subject
https://gist.github.com/antoinebou12/7a212ccd84cc95e040b2dd0e14662445

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: +1 for using `xrandr --listmonitors` :)

Comment: @simon what does the `+` sign in the output mean. I saw a monitor that do not have a `+` sign

Comment: Use a shell, not python for this.  `os.popen` is discouraged as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `python` and just `python` to get the connected monitor names:

```
$ python3 -c 'from gi.repository import Gdk; screen=Gdk.Screen.get_default(); \
[print(screen.get_monitor_plug_name(i)) for i in range(screen.get_n_monitors())]'
DP1
LVDS1
```

Comment: Nice! didn't know this one.

Comment: I get a couple of warnings: "<string>:2: DeprecationWarning: Gdk.Screen.get_n_monitors is deprecated
<string>:2: DeprecationWarning: Gdk.Screen.get_monitor_plug_name is deprecated" in Xubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add comments, I have to add an complete answer. Sorry for that.

> A terminal command to list connected screens
>
> xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'

Just a small adjustment:

```
awk '/\<connected\>/ {print $1}'< <(xrandr)
```

or

```
xrandr | awk '/\<connected\>/ {print $1}'
```

`awk` searches for the pattern within the forward slashes `/` and prints the first column.