# How can I rotate my notebook screen 90 degrees although 'xrandr --rotate' does not support it?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xrandr, rotate-monitor, display-rotation

I've got an Acer Aspire E5-773G notebook with those graphics-related specs:

```
Card-1: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940M]
Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1920x1080@60.03hz
GLX Renderer: GeForce 940M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 367.35
```

I would like a keyboard shortcut that rotates the screen (internal display) ±90°.

In *System Settings → Screen Display*, the *Rotation* setting only has the option *Normal* though.

`xrandr --rotate` fails rotating the screen:

```
bytecommander@BC-AlkaliMetal:~$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate right
xrandr: output eDP-1 cannot use rotation "right" reflection "none"

bytecommander@BC-AlkaliMetal:~$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate left
xrandr: output eDP-1 cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"
```

Here's the output of plain `xrandr` as well:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-1 disconnected
DP-1 disconnected
HDMI-2 disconnected
```

Comment: If you look up your screen's name (`xrandr`), and then does the command `xrandr --output <screenname> --rotate left` (or `right`) work? If so, all you need to do is put it under a shortcut. Make it toggle if you want.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/737139/how-can-i-quickly-toggle-monitor-orientation-with-a-shortcut-key

Comment: @JacobVlijm `xrandr --rotate` is not able to do it. It says `output eDP-1 cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"`. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Ai, I am afraid your screen won't rotate. Not with the current driver at least. I got it once as a bug report on my Take a Break application.

Comment: @JacobVlijm No way to rotate it o.O? I know that Windows rotates it without any problems and it also uses the official nvidia driver (for Windows). And would there be a way to maybe only rotate single windows or areas of the screen through software even if the driver might not support it?